# I cannot flag a comment as "Something else" with an explanation longer than 200 characters

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, error-message, character-limit

I think that there is now a 500 character limit for the "Something else" text box for flagging a comment, however the system gives me an error message when I tried to submit an explanation with 317 characters.

To reproduce:

1. Click a comment flag and select "Something else"
2. Type 10 characters into the text box and observe how the character count prompt message below the text box changes to "490 characters left".
3. Keep on typing and at "299 characters left", the prompt text color changes from gray to orange
4. Keep on typing and at 501 characters the prompt text color changes to red and the prompt message changes to "Too long by 1 character"
5. Remove some characters so that the message "nn characters left" reappears.

However, when I entered a message which was 317 characters long and then clicked "Flag comment", I saw the following error message "Please enter at least 6 and no more than 200 characters".

Tested with Chrome on Windows 10 on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).

Screen shot after clicking "Flag comment" with 317 characters in the text box:

[image]

I think that this is connected to [For both post and comment flags, increase the maximum length permitted for the text of custom flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303444/for-both-post-and-comment-flags-increase-the-maximum-length-permitted-for-the-t?rq=1)

Comment: Please wait 24-48 hours for changes to be published onto the live site.

Comment: Why wouldn't I be surprised if the database now accepts 500 chars but nobody updated the UI checks ...

Comment: @rene The DB has always accepted 600, so we only had to change the UI.

Comment: Yeah, I'm able to duplicate this issue. I'm going to keep referencing the original ticket rather than status-reviewing this but I'll get y'all updated, hopefully tomorrow since it's pretty late already.

Comment: Should be fixed. Please let me know if it's not. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oh, seems I didn't hit the submit button after testing the character count, sorry for that. One more lesson to learn, glad for the community's help.

Thanks for bringing this to our attention and for your patience while we got it fixed. Should be working now, I changed the error message, so it isn't triggered at 200 characters.